# Keycloak: How can user be filtered for a specific OIDC client by role?

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

We have one realm with many users and multiple OIDC clients configured. We would like to connect another application (OIDC Client) to the realm. Unfortunately, the client cannot check for any attributes or roles to be present.

How can I configure Keycloak to authenticate with a specific OIDC-client but return failing authentication if users have not a specific role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this type of option will not work, since authorization redirects occur before you know who the user is, and therefore before you know which roles are involved.

**WHAT I WOULD DO**

Make an authorization redirect perform only the following job:

- Signing in the user and returning the user id (sub claim), along with perhaps a couple of scopes

Then manage roles within your app - the second app should call a Web API that does this:

- Get claims from the access token, and also from other sources, then use them for identification and authorization

If a user authenticates but is not entitled to use a particular app, detect this via an API call, then present an Access Denied page in the app after login.

Comment: I was hoping that user could get authenticated in Keycloak but maybe that Keycloak still returns not authenticated if a specific role is missing. But then it looks like I need to search for another client which is capable of evaluating roles.

Comment: That would be mixing authentication and authorization - what the Authorization Server gives you is proof of authentication + the data needed for authorization. The actual enforcing of authorization needs to be done in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

To reach this you should implement the AuthenticatorFactory and Authenticator interfaces of Keycloak. Look [here](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_development/topics/auth-spi.html) for more infos.
In the authenticate() method you will write something similar to this:

```
If(client == yourClient){
// Check for roles
}
```

Otherwise, expected behaviour in case of failure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Isn't there a way to make it configurable? I don't want to do any hardcoded rule in java code.

Comment: I didn't understand you, give me an example of a hardcoded rule?

Comment: @HasniIheb the example is your code